# How to simulate editable click on content editable element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my html code

```
<ul class="options-list">
    <li contenteditable="true">Customer List</li>
    <li contenteditable="true">Product List</li>
</ul>
```

When user click on first li, content becomes editable, same happens on second div. Now requirement is, while editing on first li, if user presses enter key, I need to stop editing first li and move to second li and auto initiate edit mode.

Here is my JS code

```
$('.options-list').on('keypress', 'li', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        $(e.currentTarget).blur(); //this works
        $(e.currentTarget).siblings('li').click(); // this doesn't work
        return false;
    }
})
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `.click()`, you can use `.focus()`.

For example:

```
$('.options-list').on('keypress', 'li', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        $(e.currentTarget).blur(); 
        $(e.currentTarget).siblings('li').focus(); 
        return false;
    }
})
```

A jsfiddle demo is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6qABC/).

Comment: Problem with `focus()` is that is places the cursor at the beginning of the content instead of the mouse position. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Change `$(e.currentTarget).siblings('li').click();` to `$(e.currentTarget).next('li').focus();`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `.siblings('li').click();`

you can use `.next('li').focus();`

This would help you to move the focus to next li element,

also `.siblings('li')` would move it last li element of the list,

but `.next()` would move the focus to next li element consecutively.

Try this [jsfiddle demo example](http://jsfiddle.net/QK7j4/)

Thanks.